# Why setTimer is not working?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, timer

I have below program. I would like to know how `setTimer` works. So, I wrote a program but could not able to understand why TimerProc function not getting called. Why? What else need to be done to fire setTimer/TimerProc. Please help.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(
    HWND hwnd,  // handle of window for timer messages 
    UINT uMsg,  // WM_TIMER message
    UINT idEvent,   // timer identifier
    DWORD dwTime    // current system time
   ) {
      printf("from callback\n");

   }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   UINT timerid = SetTimer(NULL,1,1000,TimerProc);/*changed the time from 1 to 1000, but no effect*/
   printf("timerid %d\n",timerid); 
   int i,j;

      //delay loop, waiting for the callback function to be called
   for(j=0;j<0xffffffff;j++);
   /*{
   printf("%d\n", j);
   }*/

   printf("done \n");
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: if one of these answers was ok, can you accept it? (of course, I'm hoping it would be my answer!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SetTimer documentation says:
*When you specify a TimerProc callback function, the default window procedure calls the callback function when it processes WM_TIMER. Therefore, you need to dispatch messages in the calling thread, even when you use TimerProc instead of processing WM_TIMER.*

Instead the delay loop you need something like:

```
bool bStillBusy = false;


int main()
{

MSG msg;

bStillBusy  = true;

id = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 3000, (TIMERPROC) TimerProc);

while(bStillBusy) 
{
  GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
...
etc.
}
```

You set the bStillBusy to 'false' in the callback then.

Comment: Your answer really working. But here I would like to know what exactly happened when we used `GetMessage and DispatchMessage`?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak, when the timer expires it sends the WM_TIMER message, when the WM_TIMER message is dispatched to the default window procedure, which in turn calls the callback that you defined upon SetTimer.

Comment: Can we do the same without using Getmessage and Dispatchmessage?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak, there are probably a dozen other ways to implement a timer in your environment, but the one you've chosen uses messages and you are forced to use GetMessage/DispatchMessage: e.g. you could create a Thread that sleeps for X milliseconds after which it executes whatever you would have put in the callback...

Answer (score 5):

The timer works via a Windows message queue and you have a console application.

If you create a basic Win32 application so you get a window and a message loop, when the WM_TIMER message is caught by the DefWndProc() call, that's where it will do the callback. Of course you can also trap the WM_TIMER yourself.

Comment: You mean to say instead of console I need to choose `windows application` in visual studio?

Comment: That's right, or take a look at the duplicate question link in the comment on your question.

Comment: Yes. You could chose Win32 and write the message loop yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You need to learn the message loop paradigm. You are trying to use Win32 api without actually doing the right Win32 initialization and operations.

If you come from Posix, you'd could use a SIGALRM and alarm.

On windows, I'm afraid you'll have more work to do (like starting a message loop, because even when you provide a callback function, you need a message loop pumping that's calling the default message loop processing function will call your timer's callback, check this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx

> An application can process WM_TIMER messages by including a WM_TIMER case statement in the 
>   window procedure or by specifying a TimerProc callback function when creating the timer. 
>   When you specify a TimerProc callback function, the default window procedure calls the 
>   callback function when it processes WM_TIMER. Therefore, you need to dispatch messages in
>   the calling thread, even when you use TimerProc instead of processing WM_TIMER.

Answer (score 2):

Timer are handled using the normal Windows event system, so you need a normal event loop.